# Linq, c# execute method for every item in Collection (dynamic)

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I got a method - methodToExecute() that returns a bool
also have a Collection something like this `CollectionVM.SelectedItems.Cast<dynamic>()`

I need to execute methodToExecute() for every item in my Collectionand see if at least one is false.

I tried something like this

```
CollectionVM.SelectedItems.Cast<dynamic>().Any(l => (methodToExecute(l.userId) == false))
```

but in runtime i got an error

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
> dispatched operation

CAn anyone give an ideia how to solve this

Comment: Since you require class which has `userId`, instead using `dynamic`, use interface which contains such property.

Comment: Don´t use `dynamic`for something that you actually **know**. Having said this, if you know all your instances have a common member, extract an interface for them and cast every element to that instead of to `dynamic`. In fact I would avoid using `dynamic` as far as possible.

Comment: All the ViewModel is based on dynamic, that´s not an option...

Comment: Extracting an interface is nothing that breaks your code, it should allways be possible. In fact it will make your code easier to read and to maintain - and most important - it is easier to avoid nasty bugs as the compiler can help you.

Comment: Anyway: why is your VM `dynamic` in the first place? Don´t you know the types of objects you show in your view? That seems like the actual problem here.

Comment: It needs to be ready to any type, therefore we use dynamic.